# Quadratic solution is incorrect when quadratic terms is zero

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the following input:

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
%/.{a->0}
```

The solution produced by Mathematica in the first line is the result of the standard quadratic formula: $$x=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a}.$$

Because this formula is undefined at $a=0$, the second line outputs errors, "Infinite expression 1/0 encountered", followed by the output `{{x->ComplexInfinity},{x->ComplexInfinity}}`.

But if $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$ the original equation has a well-defined solution, $x=-c/b$.

Given that Mathematica is normally incredibly rigorous about its output, why is it that, conceptually, asking it to "solve this equation and evaluate the solution at zero" produces nonsense? Or, in other words, why don't we get an output that evaluates to the correct solution for $(a,b,c,x)\in\mathbb{R}^4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Reduce` which is more cautious than `Solve` regarding all possible conditions.

```
Reduce[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
% /. a -> 0
```

---

```
   (a != 0 && (x == (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a) || 
     x == (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a))) || (a == 0 && b != 0 && 
   x == -(c/b)) || (c == 0 && b == 0 && a == 0)

(b != 0 && x == -(c/b)) || (c == 0 && b == 0)
```

[image]

You can read about it in documentation of `Solve` in section  "Possible Issues" and in documentation of `Reduce` in section "Properties & Relations".

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the Option [`MaxExtraConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html)

```
Solve[a  x^2 + b  x + c == 0, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All ]

During evaluation of Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition a==0&&b==0&&c==0, the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information.
(* {{x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-(c/b), a == 0 && b != 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a), 
    a != 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a), a != 0]}} *)
```

Comment: So still `Reduce` is better at handling some conditions as in this case condition `a==0&&b==0&&c==0`.